# Convert a curl request into NodeJS request

Tags: node.js, curl, request

I am currently working on an API which gives an example of request with curl like this:

```
curl -v -H "Accept-Token: mysecret" -H "User-Token: my_user" \
     -F "filename=@my_photo.jpg" \
     -F "face_detection={\"fast\" : true}" \
     -F "age_detection={\"something\" : true}" \
     127.0.0.1:8080/vision_batch
```

When I do such a request this is what is printing netcat:

```
POST /vision_batch HTTP/1.1
Host: 127.0.0.1:9000
User-Agent: curl/7.47.0
Accept: */*
Accept-Token: test_token
User-Token: test
Content-Length: 635202
Expect: 100-continue
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=------------------------a32bed4123bace7d

--------------------------a32bed4123bace7d
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="filename"; filename="photo.png"
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
<binary_content>
--------------------------a32bed4123bace7d
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="face_detection"

{}
--------------------------a32bed4123bace7d
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="qr_recognition"

{}
--------------------------a32bed4123bace7d--
```

But I don't how to translate this multiple forms in NodeJS. I am currently doing multiple requests for each form but I have to send the image each time...

Here is my current code:

```
function getOptions(buffer, service) {
  return {
    url: 'http://127.0.0.1:9001/' + service,
    headers: headers,
    method: 'POST',
    formData: {
      filename: buffer,
      face_recognition: [],
      age_detection: []
    }
  }
}

var res_json = {};
request(getOptions(buffer, 'face_recognition'), function(error, response, body) {
});
```

The problem is that the API is returning me `no args`. And effectively, netcat is printing the following:

```
POST /vision_batch HTTP/1.1
Accept-Token: YE6geenfzrFiT88O
User-Token: ericsson_event
host: 127.0.0.1:9000
content-type: multipart/form-data; boundary=--------------------------648089449032824937983411
content-length: 663146
Connection: close

----------------------------648089449032824937983411
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="filename"
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
<binary_content>
----------------------------648089449032824937983411--
```

The problem is that I don't how to change the field formData in the request...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `formData` is nearly correct.

But, since [`request`](https://github.com/request/request#forms) uses [`form-data`](https://github.com/form-data/form-data) for (multipart) form handling, and `form-data` supports only strings, streams and `Buffer`s for values, you'll have to stringify your objects to JSON (see [usage](https://github.com/form-data/form-data#usage) and this [issue](https://github.com/request/request/issues/1495)).

This will exactly replicate your `curl` request (assuming `headers` and `buffer` populated before):

```
function getOptions(buffer, service) {
  return {
    url: 'http://127.0.0.1:9001/' + service,
    headers: headers,
    method: 'POST',
    formData: {
      filename: buffer,
      face_recognition: JSON.stringify({fast: true}),
      age_detection: JSON.stringify({something: true})
    }
  }
}
request(getOptions(buffer, 'face_recognition'));
```